# How do I set global lengths in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am stumped by the following problem. I'm not sure if this is a bug in TikZ, or if I misunderstand the way that lengths work in TeX and in TikZ.

I'd like to define a length called \mywidth, and use it in TikZ pictures in my document. I've tried the following method, which didn't work. Firstly, I added the following in my preamble:

```
\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{1cm}
```

Then inside a tikzpicture environment, I try the following code:

```
\draw (0cm,0cm) to [out=0, in=180] (\mywidth,1cm);
```

It doesn't work! I get a strange error: `Missing \csendname inserted.`

However, if I simply type

```
\draw (0cm,0cm) to [out=0, in=180] (1cm,1cm);
```

then it does work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. It's always better to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, so that other people can compile the code for themselves and also implement and test their solutions. See my answer for an example of a MWE.

Comment: Your two `\draw` lines are identical. Maybe you copied&pasted the second one incorrectly?

Comment: Hi Bruce, welcome to TeX-SX!  A minor question: do you _need_ `\width` (rather, `\mywidth` as Martin recommends) to be a genuine TeX length?  I usually handle this sort of thing with a simple macro: `\def\mywidth{1cm}`.  That works with all of the versions that Martin provides (obviously, the `\the\mywidth` don't work).  There's no need for things that _we_ consider lengths to be the same as what TeX considers lengths.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew here and maybe should have mentioned that in my answer. BTW: `\def` is basically like `\newcommand` in this case. So the more LaTeX-style way to write it would be `\newcommand{\mywidth}{1cm}`.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about my two \draw lines being identical. I fixed that and I also changed the \width to \mywidth since that wasn't a relevant part of the problem.

Comment: I'm happy to use \def\mywidth{1cm}, but I often need to do calculations like \draw (-0.5\mywidth, 0) -- (0.5\mywidth, 0);. Can this be done with a "\def" variable?

Comment: @Bruce: You need to write `-0.5*\mywidth` then. This however works only in TikZ/PGF code (or with the `calc` package IIRC) not for normal TeX length.

Comment: By the way, what does the command `\newdimen\mywidth' do? Is it equivalent to \newlength{\mywidth}?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This actually seems to be a bug of the `in` and `out` options. It should work like you have it. It does work for the normal `--` operator and for `to` without these options. It seems that in this cases the coordinates are parsed differently. You can work around this by writing `\the\width` instead. This converts the length into its string representation which avoids this parser issue. See also the question "[to path + relative coordinates in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/to-path-relative-coordinates-in-tikz)" which also suffers from similar issues related to the `to` path operator.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0cm,0cm) -- (\mywidth,1cm); % Works!
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to (\mywidth,1cm); % Works!
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to [] (\mywidth,1cm); % Works!
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to [in=180] (\mywidth,1cm); % Error
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to [out=0]  (\mywidth,1cm); % Error
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to [out=0, in=180] (\mywidth,1cm); % Error
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to [in=180] (\the\mywidth,1cm); % Works
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to [out=0]  (\the\mywidth,1cm); % Works
    \draw (0cm,0cm) to [out=0, in=180] (\the\mywidth,1cm); % Works
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you need a factor like `.5` in front of `\mywidth` you need to write `.5*\the\mywidth` instead or use `\dimexpr`: `\the\dimexpr.5\mywidth\relax`. (The `\relax` at the end might not be necessary but is there to be on the safe side)

---

Also note that `\width`, `\height`, `\depth` and `\totalheight` are often used internally by LaTeX commands to represent the dimension of a processed box and should therefore be better avoided. For example `\raisebox{<length>}{<content>}` allows you to use them to raise the content relative to its original dimension: `\raisebox{.5\height}{Text}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The \draw to operation seems pretty buggy. For instance, \draw (0,0) to[controls = +(1,0) and +(-1,0)]  (3,3);
doesn't work, but the code \draw (0,0) to[controls = +(0:1) and +(180:1)]  (3,3); does.  (!) This is causing me some serious problems since I would like to apply style declarations inside the to operator, eg. to[color=blue] but half the time the \draw to[...] doesn't work!

Comment: @Bruce: Please use backticks to mark inline code: `\`code\``. This case is not a bug, but a limitation: The `,` are used to separate option=values pairs, so they are not allowed in the option values. You need to wrap the whole value in `{ }` here: `\draw (0,0) to[controls = {+(1,0) and +(-1,0)}] (3,3);` then it should work.

Comment: If it's a bug can someone please report it?

Comment: I would hesitate at calling this a _bug_.  From a little experimentation, this might be to do with expansion.  `pgfmath` tries to expand the coordinates to find numbers on which to compute, and if it ends up with unknown stuff then it assumes that they are node names.  Since `\mywidth` isn't expandable, `pgfmath` assumes that `\mywidth,1cm` is a node name.  The moral of the story is that you shouldn't confuse _TeX lengths_ with _TikZ lengths_.  Best to stay on the "high level" with pure macros unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Andrew: No, IIRC from my last look on the code the normal parsing code of TikZ reads the content token-wise and then checks if the token is a dimension or counter register and then extracts its numeric content from it. This is the reason why it works with `--`. The bug here is the inconsistency. Apparently `to [in=...,out=...]` handles the input differently!

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the explanation about the commas. I'm glad there is a workaround.

Comment: @Andrew: Another issue is that [`\dimexpr` and `\numexpr` are not directly supported by TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3165954&group_id=142562&atid=752792). Using `\the` in front of them works however, because they then get expanded. The problem is that you can't change your packages from using `\setlength` to `\pgfsetlength` internally because you could break user code!! This affected me for my `adjustbox` package. Ok, I figured it out before the first release so I hadn't any backwards compatibility issues :-)

Comment: Martin: Ah, okay.  More complicated than I thought.  Incidentally, the question you linked to in your answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/to-path-relative-coordinates-in-tikz, appears to be solved in PGF2.10.  I just updated my answer there.