# Using the TikZ spy library to spy on a pixel value in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, spy

I tried to use the `TikZ`library `spy` to zoom in on a certain pixel image; I am drawing in the image using a scope and red about the problem concerning coordinates in scopes here 
[Magnify part of picture with TikZ spy, expressed in relative scoped coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168761/magnify-part-of-picture-with-tikz-spy-expressed-in-relative-scoped-coordinates)

My problem is, that spy seems to place the point *in* the image correctly but then chooses the wrong part to magnify, for example in the MWE

```
\documentclass[german,10pt,xcolor=colortbl,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\RequirePackage{xltxtra}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Example}{Spy on Images in Beamer}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,size=.1\textwidth, magnification=3, connect spies}]
            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {%
            % \includegraphics[height=.5\textwdth]{exampleA}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[draw=blue,fill=green!50] (0,0) rectangle (.5\textwidth,.5\textwidth);
                \shade[top color=black, bottom color=white] (.25\textwidth,.25\textwidth) rectangle (.5\textwidth,.5\textwidth);                    
            \end{tikzpicture}
            };
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                % Draw besides image
                \shade[top color=red, bottom color=blue] (1.025,.66) rectangle (1.075,1);
                \node (spy1) at (128/256,192/256) {};
                \coordinate (spyto1) at (-.5,.75); 
                \spy [black,thick] on (spy1) in node at (spyto1);
                \node (spy2) at (256/256,224/256) {};
                \coordinate (spyto2) at (-.5,.25); 
                \spy [black,thick] on (spy2) in node at (spyto2);
            \end{scope}
            % Adress a point in “pixels”
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The magnification should be directly at the border of the green part to the shade. nevertheless, the magnification shows only green and playing around with the second one, i think it's off by both directions to the lower left.

[image: Wrong spy in beamer with scopes]

I have seen no way to obtain information about the magnification process, so - any clues, which computation is still affected by some wrong **scoped** coordinates would be very helpful.

*Edit:* As Andrew noted, this is fixed (also for me now) with TikZ/PGF 3.0; though if anybody could present details on what is going wrong here - feel free to share.

Comment: What version of TikZ are you using?  It works for me with TikZ3.0.

Comment: I think it's the 2.10; that one usually shipped with MacTeX 2013.

Comment: Any chance of upgrading?  It's really worth it.

Comment: I tried just putting it into my local directory (`~Library/texmf` on a Mac) which didn't work yet; nevertheless I am not the only one working with these graphics; i'll try to upgrade but a solution for the 2013-TeXLive would be nice

Comment: So i managed to locally install Tikz/PGF 3.0 which solves the problem for me. If you could provide your comment as an answer, i'm glad to accept it @Andrew Stacey - if you know details, even more.

Comment: @LoopSpace would you like to write a quick answer for this one?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by updating the `pgf` package.

Comment: I agree on that. For this question - though the application is quite interesting - updating resolved the problem.