# I want to organize three images in a frame, simulating the effect of a zoom,

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, zooming

[image: This is an example of what i want to create]

I have three images, I want to organize them in a frame to cause the effect of a zoom, similar to the image I have posted above. In this image the galaxy is at left, but i want to learn how to modified this position in the code, becouse acctually I need the second image(in our case, the Solar System) at right.

It is no necessarily that one image overlap the other, but it is not a problem if this occurs

I have no clue how to do it, any advice?

Comment: what's the format of the images? Just bitmaps or tikz/ps? Do you have them as separate files?

Comment: @Bordaigorl I have them in  separate files in png format.

Comment: So basically you need to overlay several different images.  \raisebox, \llap and \rlap can be used to overlay things, but the most elegant solution would be to use tikz to overlay nodes containing \includegraphics.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple version based on John Kormylo's comment and [Caramdir's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/). (Some explanation in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214366/) to another question.) Background image courtesy of NASA.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (nasa) [anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.25]{pia17172}};
%   \draw [help lines] (nasa.south west) grid (nasa.north east);% for placing help with specifying locations
    \begin{scope}[x=(nasa.south east), y=(nasa.north west)]
      \node [pin={[pin distance=300, pin edge={thick, white}]-5:{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{tiger}}}] at (.615,.275) {};
      \node [font=\Huge\bfseries, text=white, anchor=south west] {Credit: NASA};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tiger zoom on NASA image]