# Define \coordinate relative to other \coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

i have a tikz question. Is it possible to use relative coordinates in a \coordinate definition? I have to define a lot of coordinates and it would be much easier if i could define those relative to already defined coordinates like this:

```
\coordinate (A) at (0.0, 0.0);
\coordinate (B) at (A)+(120:1);
```

As you can see, i want to especially use the angle:length notation here. But in general i want to define the coordinate B relative to A. Is this possible?

Comment: Use the tikz calc library, `($(A) +(120:1)$)`

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48756/4778, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3217/4778

Comment: Another solution without `calc` library: `\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(120:1)}]A);`. Be careful with syntax, as `(120:1)` uses parenthesis, it must be included into a pair of braces `{ (120:1)}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, it wouldn't. I checked just to be sure.

Comment: Also \path (A) +(120:1) coordinate (B);   (@cfr - I assume the ++ was what you were referring to.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo I didn't mean that `++` wouldn't work. I meant that `+` will not, in fact, put the B on top of the A. ;)

Comment: @cfr - That's what I thought.  I prefer to use + instead of ++ whenever possible.

Answer (score 9):

`\coordinate` is only a shorthand for `\path coordinate`.  You may thus place coordinates along an arbitrary path which supports relative coordinates without a hassle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \path (A) +(120:1) coordinate (B);
  % or \path (A) -- +(120:1) coordinate (B);

  \draw (A) circle (2pt);
  \draw (B) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]